# psycopg2 how deal with TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this code:

```
ip = "127.0.0.1"
sql = "select count(*) from radacct where nasipaddress=%s"
cur.execute(sql,ip)
```

But I get an error like

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can i pass the parameters to psycopg2 in the correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sql arguments you pass to `execute` must be in a tuple or list, even if there's only one of them. This is noted in the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

> For positional variables binding, the second argument must always be a
>   sequence, even if it contains a single variable. And remember that
>   Python requires a comma to create a single element tuple:

So you need to do it like this:

```
ip ="127.0.0.1" 
sql="select count(*) from radacct where nasipaddress=%s"
cur.execute(sql, (ip,))
```