# How to use variables and OR cunjunctions in SQL statement in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I have a list of Ids in a list named `res` that I want to use line by line as WHERE conditions on a SQL query before saving the results in an array :

```
                              ids
grupos                           
0       [160, 161, 365, 386, 471]
1                      [296, 306]
```

Here is what I tried to insert it in a SQL query :

```
listado = [None]*len(res)
# We store the hashtags that describes the best the groups
# We iterate on the people of a group to construct the WHERE condition
print "res : ", res
for i in (0,len(res)):        

conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
cur = conn.cursor()

listado = [None]*len(res)
for i in (0,len(res)):        
    print "res[i:p] : ", res.iloc[i]['ids']
    cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id  FROM subscriber_hashtag
    -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
    -- join para que los usarios  estan vinculados con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
    -- recobremos los "me gusta"
    WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
    GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",(res.iloc[i]['ids']))

    n = cur.fetchall()
    listado[i] = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1]} for elem in n]
```

#### Data for a reproducible example

Providing the further data informations :

```
subscriber_id hashtag_id
160           345
160           347
161           345
160           334
161           347
306           325
296           362
306           324
296           326
161           322
160           322
```

The output should, here, be like :

```
{0:[324,1],[325,1],[326,1],[362,1], 1 : [345,2],[347,2],[334,1]}
```

#### Current error message

ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 50))

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f7c3c5b81303> in <module>()
     39         WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
     40         GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
---> 41             ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",(res.iloc[i]['ids']))
     42 
     43         n = cur.fetchall()
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: what is the error of current scenario

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I just added the error message, but the query was known to be not working as far as I don't know how many conditions I will have with the `WHERE` statement

Comment: ` "me gusta"` check on this line. You sure you are using the raw string correctly?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I am not sure to understand very well the question but everything is okay on this line, it is a comment, the one which is not is the `WHERE` as far as it dosn't know where to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [tuples adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation):

> Python tuples are converted into a syntax suitable for the SQL IN operator and to represent a composite type:

Pass ids as a tuple query argument, so your argument to execute is a 1-tuple of tuple of ids, and drop the manual parentheses around `%s`. At the moment your `(res.iloc[i]['ids'])` is nothing but a sequence expression in redundant parentheses, so `execute()` uses it as the argument sequence, which causes your TypeError exception; your argument sequence has more arguments than the query has placeholders.

Try `(tuple(res.iloc[i]['ids']),)` instead. Note the comma, it is a [very common error to omit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292409/psycopg2-how-deal-with-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-form). All in all:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), 
subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
FROM subscriber_hashtag
INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
WHERE subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id in %s
GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",
(tuple(res.iloc[i]['ids']),))
```

Your for-loop is a bit strange, since you iterate over a 2-tuple `(0, len(res))`.  Perhaps you meant `range(len(res))`. You could also just iterate over the Pandas Series:

```
for i, ids in enumerate(res['ids']):
    ...
    cur.execute(..., (tuple(ids),))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I think there is an error as far as it tells me there is a `missing FROM-clause entry for table "subscriber_hastag"` on `WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (160, 161, ...`

Comment: That's a typo. "hastag" vs. "hashtag".

Comment: There is an issue : Te pure SQL query and the python nested query don't give the same output ...

Comment: There are no nested queries in the given SQL. Since the question was not about the correctness of the given SQL statement and logic, but how to use a list of values in a WHERE-clause with the IN operator, this is proving off topic. Please ask a new question about that.

Comment: Okay, I just did. But how can I print out the result of the different groups still ?